# How to fix a big gap between two references in a latex template?

Tags: bibtex

I prepared my article with a template of a journal, but I faced a big gap between references 4 and 5. Also, the arrangement of the references in my article is changing randomly; for example, ref 1 written 10, ref 10 written 5, and so on not like the arrangement in the natbib file. How can I fix this problem?[image]

Comment: the order in the bib file is not relevant, the references will be ordered in order of use or (as here) order of author names. The big gap is due to code you have not shown.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.